# How to delay video streaming in MPMoviePlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am playing video stream from urls,in MPMoviePlayer.When I click the play button,Json

parsing happens and video is getting played after a buffer. all the videos are 30s. After the

first buffer video plays for 5-6 seconds,and stops.then again buffers and play.It continues

till 30th second.So the viewers get disturbed a lot. Is there any idea to overcome this?

Comment: where do you read your video stream from?

Answer (score 0):

one shortcut idea is you out

```
sleep(4);
```

in before playing the player

~thanking You